# Execute C on a split screen in vim

Tags: c++, c, linux, vim, ide

When I execute a C program in vim using `:!./%<`, I would like to be able to see my code (on the left side of a split screen), as well as the stdout results from the execution of the program (on the right side of the split screen). At the moment, the output of the program execution is blocking the view of my code until I hit `ENTER`, but then I can no longer see the program output.

How do I execute a C program in vim so that I can see both of its code and its execution results together on a split screen ?? I tried piping the output using `:!./%<|vert copen`, but failed. I am using Linux.

Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: Most use tmux to do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Install `vimshell` then type `:VimShellInteractive` to transform a vim window (a split for example) into an instance of a shell where you can still use vim commands.

Comment: 'sudo apt-get install vimshell' (or vim-shell) returns an error. Where can I get hold of vimshell and information on compiling it in ubuntu?

Comment: vimshell is here: https://github.com/Shougo/vimshell.vim and how to install is explained in the vimshell.txt that you can find on that same page.